# Filling up array of objects from AsyncStorage

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-native, asyncstorage

I am new to React Native and kind of new to javascript as well.
The problem i am facing is:
I am getting the instances of objects from AsyncStorage on react Native.
But when I fill the array doing `"rests.push(JSON.parse(rest))""`
It fills the array but not on the right way.

Following is the image of
[what is, and what it should be, respectively.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChLai.png)

The code that I am using to fill the array is as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
AsyncStorage.getItem(result[i].toString(), (err, rest) => {
parsedRest = JSON.parse(rest);
rests.push(parsedRest);
});
}
```

[FILLED ARRAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVr7s.png)

Any help would be thankful.

Vitor

Comment: What is AsyncStorage.getItem(result[i].toString()) returning?

Comment: the loop goes through all the items on the store.
It is returning a json string, like so:
{"id":9,"rest_name":"Termodinamica","description":"Formula das trocas de calor e exercicio de exemplo.. ","favorite":0,"recent":0}
I meant, this is the "rest" parameter

Comment: Where is your console log? if it's immediately after the for-loop then the issue is likely to be that it's being executed before the array has been populated as `getItem` is asynchronous.

Comment: console.log is immediately after the for loop, but the array is filling up.
I have updated the post above, the filled array is on the FILLED ARRAY link.
Any ideas would be appreciate

Comment: SOLVED - instead of setting several keys for each term on the Storage, I am setting one key for the whole list. Not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @VítorLima if you're using AsyncStorage heavily at all and you don't want to bother with the JSON.parsing and JSON.stringifying you could use react-native-simple-store to take care of this for you. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-store)